# Validate html form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I want to validate user input with javascript before sending data to the server, but when I try the browser doesn't display the alert message.

I cannot find the problem. Please help me. Thank you!

My HTML:

```
    <title>Login Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/functions.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="content">

         <form name="signin_form"  action="../processes/login_process.php" onsubmit="return checkLoginData()"  method="POST">

          <h1>Accesso Utente</h1>

          <p>
             <label for='tf_nick'>Nick</label>
             <input type='text' id='tf_nick' name='tf_nick' value="">

             <label for='tf_password'>Password</label>
             <input type='password' id='tf_password' name='tf_password' value=''>

             <input type='submit' value='OK'>
             <input type='reset' value='Pulisci'>
           </p>

        </form>

     </div>

</body>
```

My JavaScript:

```
    function checkLoginData(){

        var formObj = document.signin_form;     
        var nick    = "" + formObj.tf_nick.value;
        var pass    = "" + formObj.tf_password.value;

        if ( nick == "" ) {
            alert("Inserisci il nick per accedere!");
            return false;

        } else if ( pass == "" ) {
            alert("Inserisci la password per accedere!");
            return false;

        } else {

            var regExNick = /(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z%])^[a-zA-Z0-9%]{3,6}$/;        
            var regExPass = /(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])^[a-zA-Z]{4,8}$/;

            if ( !regExNick.test(nick) ){
                alert("Nick non valido!");
                return false;

            } else if ( !regExPass.test(pass) ) {
                alert("Password non valida!");
                return false;

            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the file system:

```
main_folder/pages/login.php
main_folder/js/functions.js
```

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like checking if your code runs at all, and if it does, what section it fails? Plus, while client-side JS validation is all fine and dandy for immediately feedback, do not **EVER** use ONLY js validation. it's too easy to bypass.

Comment: wrap return checkLoginData in a function.

Comment: @matt: uh, wrap a function call in a function? why?

Comment: Use a decent browser, use a decent debugger attached to it (firebug or integrated debugger in chrome), add breakpoint everywhere in your code (use the `debugger;` statement) and check what is wrong.

Comment: I just tested this and it works fine on Chrome.

Comment: @MarcB: I also use php server-side script to validate the data but I want to add javascript validation client-side to prevent network overload.

Answer (score 0):

I created this jsfiddle which is just a copy/pasted from your code and there it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/872d6ssn/1/ (code included below because stackoverflow demands that, but it's just a copy)

Are you sure you include the js file in the correct way? I seems like you're not including the file at all.

HTML

```
      <h1>Accesso Utente</h1>

      <p>
         <label for='tf_nick'>Nick</label>
         <input type='text' id='tf_nick' name='tf_nick' value="">

         <label for='tf_password'>Password</label>
         <input type='password' id='tf_password' name='tf_password' value=''>

         <input type='submit' value='OK'>
         <input type='reset' value='Pulisci'>
       </p>

    </form>
```

JavaScript

```
  function checkLoginData(){
    var formObj = document.signin_form;     
    var nick    = "" + formObj.tf_nick.value;
    var pass    = "" + formObj.tf_password.value;

    if ( nick == "" ) {
        alert("Inserisci il nick per accedere!");
        return false;

    } else if ( pass == "" ) {
        alert("Inserisci la password per accedere!");
        return false;

    } else {

        var regExNick = /(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z%])^[a-zA-Z0-9%]{3,6}$/;        
        var regExPass = /(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])^[a-zA-Z]{4,8}$/;

        if ( !regExNick.test(nick) ){
            alert("Nick non valido!");
            return false;

        } else if ( !regExPass.test(pass) ) {
            alert("Password non valida!");
            return false;

        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers.
I tried the jsfiddle and it works, so I think that the problem is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/functions.js"></script>
```

Probably the source is not correct because the IE debugger says:

```
'checkLoginData' is undefined
```

I have to set the correct path of my javascript file.
The file system is like this:

```
main_folder/pages/login.php
main_folder/js/functions.js
```

Why this `src="../js/functions.js"` is not correct?

Thank you for the help!